# How does Android device monitor enable inspection/dump of webviews?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand why I get a correct hierarchy dump of a webview after I start the Android device monitor (SDK/tools/monitor.bat) but not before. It's enough to simply start it once, after that I can close it and it still work every time (until I reboot the device). So it must send some kind of command or do something.

This is the command I use:

```
adb shell uiautomator dump
```

**Before I open Android device monitor:**

[image]

**After I open Android device monitor:**

[image]

As you can see in the second image I can now see all the different nodes inside the webview.

I tried to look through the console output to see if it send some kind of command to the device but I'm not really sure what  I should look for. Anyone have an idea on what it can be?